# IOS Login JSON parser with session Id from WebService

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, storyboard, restkit

Hi I am new to IOS development. I am developing an app that pulls data from a webservice. It has login and logout session and a whole lot of JSON API calls that i intent to implement using RestKit.

Now the issue is my login is working and gets success code 200 but fails to go to the next View Controller Scene because. I don't know how to get the sessionId.

Here is my code and JSON ;

```html
{
  "details": {
    "username": "MY USER NAME",
"password": "MY MD5 CONVERTED PASS" }
}


Expected Returned JSON syntax (Success)

{
  "response": {
"code": 200,
"resp_code": "USER_SESSION_LOGGED_IN", "sid": "as4ads68ds468486essf879g8de9sdg", "session_info": {
"details": {
"firstname" : "MY NAME",
"email_address" : "MY EMAIL", "company_id" : 1,
"user_id" : 1,
"surname" : "MY SURNAME",
"cell_number" : "MY NUMBER",
"username" : "MY USERNAME"
} }
} }
//
//  ViewController.m
//
//  Created by Cockpit Alien on 2014/10/27.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 CockpitAlien. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*+ (NSString*)md5HexDigest:(NSString*)input
{
    const char* str = [input UTF8String];
    unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_MD5(str, strlen(str), result);
    
    NSMutableString *ret = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH*2];
    for(int i = 0; i<CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        [ret appendFormat:@"%02x",result[i]];
    }
    return ret;
}*/

- (NSString *) md5:(NSString *) input
{
    const char *cStr = [input UTF8String];
    unsigned char digest[16];
    CC_MD5( cStr, strlen(cStr), digest ); // This is the md5 call
    
    NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];
    
    return  output;
    
}

- (IBAction)signinClicked:(id)sender {
    NSInteger success = 0;
    NSString *username = self.txtUsername.text;
    NSString *password = self.txtPassword.text;
    NSString *md5Password = [self md5:password];
    
    @try {
        
        if([username isEqualToString:@""] || [password isEqualToString:@""] ) {
            [self alertStatus:@"Please enter Email and Password" :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];
            
        } else {
            NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",username,md5Password];
            NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);
            // Create the request
            NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"MY JSON HTTP/S URL HERE"];
            
            NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
            
            NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
            
            
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
            NSLog(@"Request Mutable, %@", request);
            [request setURL:url];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
            [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [request setHTTPBody:postData];
            
            //[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];
            
            NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
            NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
            
            // Create url connetion and fire requests
            NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                                  returningResponse:&response
                                                              error:&error];
            
            NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);
            
            if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300)
            {
                NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);
                
                NSError *error = nil;
                NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                                          JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                                          options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                          error:&error];
                
                success = [jsonData[@"success"] integerValue];
                NSLog(@"Success: %ld",(long)success);
                
                if(success == 1)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
                } else {
                    
                    NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) jsonData[@"error_message"];
                    [self alertStatus:error_msg :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];
                    NSLog(@"Loging failed");
                }
                
            } else {
                //if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                [self alertStatus:@"Connection Failed" :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];
            }
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
        [self alertStatus:@"Sign in Failed." :@"Error!" :0];
    }
    if (success) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login_success" sender:self];
    }
}

- (void) alertStatus:(NSString *)msg :(NSString *)title :(int) tag
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                        message:msg
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    alertView.tag = tag;
    [alertView show];
}
@end


//
//  ViewController.h
//      
//  Created by CockPit on 2014/10/27.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 CockpitAliens. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtUsername;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtPassword;
- (IBAction)signinClicked:(id)sender;

@end
```

Here is my storyboard. I want to be able to login and go to the next view controller. because I am going to also have to logout the sessionId parsing this JSON.

[image]

Comment: What does this `NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);` show you

Comment: I will post the response data I get now

Comment: Post data: username=cockpit&password=vsgsvah24bsbsbs5tbsb

Comment: Thats your post data, we need to see the response data

Comment: check for segue Identifier it is correct or not, it should be exact as in xib

Comment: Where is any RestKit code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your`signinClicked` method,

```
- (IBAction)signinClicked:(id)sender 
{
   ....
   ....

   if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300)
   {
   ....
   ....
    if(success == 1)
    {
       NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
    }
   ....
   ....
   }

   ....
   ....
}
```

So you are doing nothing else than printing **NSLog**. You are checking *statusCode* is successful or not and in that checking *success* variable value. In that if condition you should require executable code or method call, which will push application for further execution.

Comment: Yes you are right if (success == 1) I believe there should be a code to action what to do next in that case. Please help

Comment: if(success == 1)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
                    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@ "login success" sender:self];
                } else {

Comment: if i add this code still don't get the view controller to go to login success screen

Comment: Then there must be some issue with your storyboard segue connection. Try removing your current connection and add new with different identifier name.

Comment: That's the response. Unless I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I still don't know why I can't login in